# unable to install python dev in i.mx6ul with yocto core image basic

Tags: linux, python, yocto-project

I want to install `python` dev-0.4.0 in my nxp i.mx6ul arm development board with linux (core-image-basic) build using yocto project.

This is the error I got:

```
root@localhost:~/packages/dev-0.4.0# python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 12, in <module>
    import dev.release.xdistutils as dist
  File "dev/__init__.py", line 3
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xf0' in file dev/__init__.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already add meta-python, then edit local.conf and add:

```
 IMAGE_INSTALL += "python-dev"
```

this will add python header on /usr/include/python2.7/
, so if you need python3-dev then

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "python3-dev"
```

will do the job.

Hope this can help you, that worked for me.